# Scroll pop menu without mouse wheel

Tags: interface, mouse

For example, when I have many View Layers in a scene:

[image]

While there is a small triangle pointing down, no matter where I move my cursor to, the menu doesn't scroll. Clicking the triangle doesn't work either. Pressing <kbd>DOWN</kbd> on keyboard does scroll it, but is there any way to do this with a mouse (without scroll wheel) only?

Comment: Well, you can always use the search bar. It's active - just start typing :).